# Why there is no possibility to create extensions for 'type instance'

Tags: c#, .net

I wonder why it is not possible to create extension methods for a 'type instance'. If this functionality had been presented it would have been possible to 'extend' static classes for example.

Example:

```
public static class A
{
  public static void Method()
  {
  }
}

public static class AExtensions
{
  public static void Method2(this static A a)
  {
      // something
  }
}
```

Comment: How exactly would you use such extension methods? If you're specifying the class name, you can just do that with the "new" class...

Comment: Adds complication to method invocation, instead of being able to do a type lookup to confirm that the type has the method signature it would have to query the instance. Now what happens if you cast it to something else? Does that method carry over? What if there is a namespace conflict that didn't exist before? etc. etc.

Comment: Jon Skeet - extend static classes from third parties, without wrraping.

Answer (score 1):

Well of course the real answer is: the cost of developing such a feature far outweighs the potential benefits.

However, just think about it. What are you actually going to get from that feature? You can already do this perfectly legally, which is effectively "extending" the static class.

```
// 3rd party library
public static class A {
  public static void Method() {
  }
}

// my source code
public static class AExtensions {
  public static void Method2() {
  }
}
```

If you think that by extending class `A` you will somehow gain access to all its `internal` and `private` members, then you won't be able to do that, it would break encapsulation. You can't do that with instance extension methods either.